# estoy tratando de llamar datos dentro de un combobox proveniente de mysql, pero me sale error al cargarlo

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="text" name="id_factura" id="id_factura" />
<label >usuario:</label>
<select name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario">

<?php

     $sql="SELECT * FROM  usuario";
     $result=$cone->query($sql);


     while($fila=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value='".$fila['id_usuario']."'>".$fila['nombre_usuario']."</option>";
     }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Organiza tu pregunta. Que es este codigo? que hace? donde esta el error? cual es el error? asi como esta, no se entiende nada de nada.